# How to customize context menu for specific words in the text area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know how to create tags for specific fields in the text area so that I can create a context menu in the text area
Is this appropriate?when the specific words are clicked Then the context menu will open I don't know how to create tags for specific words in text area

I can benefit
Create a context menu in the text area
I have that context menu
It only works on paragraphs
You help me use them into the textarea
I tried to highlight the wrong words in the textarea
I was successful in a project but couldn't add a context menu
You can help me look at both of my projects

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>rebaz</title>

    <style>
      .custom-context-menu {
        z-index: 1100;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background: white;
      }

      .custom-context-menu li {
        padding: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .custom-context-menu li:hover {
        background-color: aqua;
      }

      .backdrop {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="card">
    <p>
      This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples
      without prior coordination or asking for permission.
    </p>

    <ul class="custom-context-menu">
      <li>rule</li>
      <li>slde</li>
      <li>rebaz</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="backdrop"></div>

    <script>
      const words = $("p").text().split(/\s+/);
      const text = words.join("</span> <span>");

      let incorrectWord = null;

      $("p")
        .first()
        .html("<span>" + text + "</span>");

      const customContextMenu = $(".custom-context-menu");
      const backdrop = $(".backdrop");

      $("span").on("click", function (e) {
        let topPosition = e.clientY;
        let leftPosition = e.clientX;
        customContextMenu.show();
        backdrop.show();

        incorrectWord = $(e.target);

        customContextMenu.css("left", leftPosition + "px");
        customContextMenu.css("top", topPosition + "px");
      });

      customContextMenu.find("li").on("click", function () {
        const chosenWord = $(this).html();
        incorrectWord.html(chosenWord);
        customContextMenu.hide();
        backdrop.hide();
      });

      backdrop.on("click", () => {
        customContextMenu.hide();
        backdrop.hide();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```